# Lodash way of adding property to object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an object

```
{ id1: {name: 'John'}, id2: {name: 'Mary'} }
```

I need to `assign` a property to each person. I need to achieve this

```
{ id1: {name: 'John', married: false}, id2: {name: 'Mary', married: false} }
```

I can do it by `forEach` over the `_.values` but it doesn't seem like the best way. Is there a *LoDash* way to do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `_.mapValues`

```
var res = _.mapValues(data, function(val, key) {
    val.married = false;
    return val;
})
```

to prevent the mutation of the original data

```
var res = _.mapValues(data, function(val, key) {
    return _.merge({}, val, {married: false});
})
```

to mutate in place

```
_.mapValues(data, function(val, key) {
    val.married = false;
})
```

Comment: Use `_.assign({}, obj, { married: false })` to prevent the mutation of the original data.

Comment: Is there a way to do it in place?

Answer (score 0):

ES6 version, probably also the fastest...?

```js
var obj = { id1: {name: 'John'}, id2: {name: 'Mary'} }

for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(obj))
  val.married = false
  
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use _.mapValues,

```
    let rows = { id1: {name: 'John'}, id2: {name: 'Mary'} };

    _.mapValues(rows, (value, key) => {
        value.married = false;
    });
```

Output:-

```
{id1: {name: "John", married: false}, id2: {name: "Mary", married: false}}
```